# Endpoint deployment state is failing, while deploying a model through AKSCompute/AMLCompute (both)

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-deployment, azureml-python-sdk

Here, when I ran the code for deployment using AKSCompute, I am getting an error

> Tips: You can try get_logs(): https://aka.ms/debugimage#dockerlog or local deployment: https://aka.ms/debugimage#debug-locally to debug if deployment takes longer than 10 minutes.
> Running
> 2023-04-20 11:42:01+05:30 Creating Container Registry if not exists.
> 2023-04-20 11:42:01+05:30 Registering the environment.
> 2023-04-20 11:42:02+05:30 Use the existing image.
> 2023-04-20 11:42:03+05:30 Creating resources in AKS.
> 2023-04-20 11:42:04+05:30 Submitting deployment to compute.
> 2023-04-20 11:42:04+05:30 Checking the status of deployment aiops-model-service-error.
> Failed
> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
> Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Failed
> Operation ID: f65019a8-3178-48e7-b28b-1c65d28f13de
> More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
> Error:
> {
> "code": "KubernetesDeploymentFailed",
> "statusCode": 400,
> "message": "Kubernetes Deployment failed",
> "details": [
> {
> "code": "CrashLoopBackOff",
> "message": "Your container application crashed as it does not have AzureML serving stack.
> Make sure you have 'azureml-defaults>=1.0.45' package in your pip dependencies, it contains requirements for the AzureML serving stack."
> },
> {
> "code": "DeploymentFailed",
> "message": "Your container endpoint is not available. Please follow the steps to debug:

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(source_directory = './service_files',
                                   entry_script="scoring_script.py",
                                   environment=myenv)

deploy_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 0.1,
                                                   memory_gb = 0.5)

model = ws.models['model_from_run_local_5']

service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                       name = 'aiops-model-service-error',
                       models = [model],
                       inference_config = inference_config,
                       deployment_config = deploy_config,
                       deployment_target = production_cluster)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
```

This is the code and environment I used[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE2dY.png). I even tried using AMLCompute but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

you have uncaught exceptions in your init() function that is triggering the CrashLoopBackOff error. you can follow ERROR: [ResourceNotReady part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli#error-resourcenotready).  Did you inspect the docker logs for details?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli#error-kubernetescrashloopbackoff